# I can't seem to make the Microsoft CSP SDK for .NET work

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I am trying to migrate my CSP code from PHP with Rest API to C# .NET using the SDK, but I can't seem to make any sample work.

Right now I am using Azure Functions to deploy the code, and while debugging it locally, I have a constant error of:

```
error CS0103: The name 'PartnerCredentials' does not exist in the current context
```

The sample I am trying to make work right now is:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Store.PartnerCenter;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace cspTest
{
    public static class cspTest
    {
        [FunctionName("cspTest")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            IPartnerCredentials partnerCredentials =
                PartnerCredentials.Instance.GenerateByApplicationCredentials(secret, secret,login.microsoftonline.com");

            //  Create operations instance with partnerCredentials.
            return PartnerService.Instance.CreatePartnerOperations(partnerCredentials);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, this is my first time working both with AZ and .NET/C# so I'm not sure if I'm missing something really obvious or if I am doing a really stupid mistake.

Comment: what is the .net version you are using ?

Comment: Did you check `PartnerCredentials`' namespace? Is it in the `using`s?

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT I'm using the  3.1.24 version.
@Fildor When I try adding "using PartnerCredentials" it says ```The type or namespace name 'PartnerCredentials' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)``` and ```Unnecesary using directive```. It's supposed to be part of the Microsoft CSP SDK, as they don't have any specific use for it, or at least that's what I think

Comment: You need to have `using Microsoft.Store.PartnerCenter.Extensions;` : [PartnerCredentials Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.store.partnercenter.extensions.partnercredentials?view=partnercenter-dotnet-latest)

Comment: You might have missed creating the class file related to PartnerCredentials

Comment: @Fildor damn... Thanks a lot, that was something really stupid that I was missing, but couldn't find it no matter what. Totally bookmarkign that page for future references and errors. Thanks a lot for real!

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by @Fildor in the comments:

You need to have using Microsoft.Store.PartnerCenter.Extensions; : [PartnerCredentials Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.store.partnercenter.extensions.partnercredentials?view=partnercenter-dotnet-latest)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).